# Not able to send media on Whatsapp...Moto X

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I just upgraded to Moto X from Motorola Photon. I am not being able to send/receive any picture or media files. The settings for media is turned on but still the media button in mot highlighting.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I see your Android 4.2 tag, but I just want to ask so we can be certain: Are you running 4.2 or 4.4?

Answer (score 1):

This can be dependant on the app itself being compatible with your version of android, or the phone itself. Without more information, this is a hard question to answer. I've heard that Whatsapp doesnt like Android 4.4 (KitKat) just yet, or it could be a simple problem with the app that the developer hasn't fixed yet. If all else fails, give it time for the devs to fix the app, make sure settings on your phone allow it the app to work right, or just try reinstalling the app and restarting your phone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my motorola Moto G . Try going to Configuration -> Apps , then touch the menu button at the right top and select "Reset apps configuration". 
This solved my problem. I hope this help ! .

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a third party music player that will allow to send audio files through WhatsApp. One such application is [Android Music player by JRT Studio](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrtstudio.music).

Answer (score -1):

After some tests .. I realized that a temporary solution could be remove the Google Play Music application updates.